# Jquery double message after ajax request

Tags: ajax, jquery

I am struggling with the follow thing. I have an user page where people can make groups to store there content. Its also possible to delete a group. Wen someone deleted his group, this will be done by ajax so there is no page reload. After this ajax request, I show a message that the group is deleted.

The problem;
When a user delete a group, the message is showing well. When the user delete a second group the message is showing twice, so the last message isn't really removed but comes back by another ajax request. How can I resolve this?

Code sample;

```
$(function () {
    var form = $('form.groups select');
    $("a.remove-group", this).live("click", function(){

        var group_name  = $(this).attr("id");
        var string = 'group_name=' + group_name;

        $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "/settings/delete/",
               data: string,
               cache: false,
               success: function() {
                   $('.fullpage').prepend('<div class="hide-message alert">Group removed</div>');
                   $("#ordered").load('/settings/managmant/');
                }
             });

    });
});
```

To remove the message after its loaded;

```
setTimeout(function() {
   $('.hide-message').slideUp('slow').remove();
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

every time you call `prepend()` you are adding an additional message to the DOM.

You should prepend the message outside your click function and then just show/hide it on success.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation of this function!

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are hiding the div/message instead of removing it.  Use the Remove() function to remove the class "hide-message alert", then it won't pop next time you delete.

Edit: My bad, i see you already have Remove() at the end - but i don't think you're calling it right because in the message/div your class has two names in it. you might have to ref it by using both names like that:

$('.hide-message alert').remove();

Comment: you don't have to use both selectors

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("a.remove-group", this).die('click').live("click", function(){
```

Answer (score 0):

When you delete something you prepend an additional ".hide-message" div to the page.

```
$('.fullpage').prepend('<div class="hide-message alert">Group removed</div>');
```

Then you slideUp() the ".hide-message" divs...

```
$('.hide-message').slideUp('slow')
```

...all of these added divs will be shown, one per group you have deleted.